# When connecting it to my react frontend. I get spotipy invalid client. However example works just fine on backend host

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

Using the example for testing: https://github.com/spotipy-dev/spotipy/blob/master/examples/app.py

Trying to use a React frontend that gets the html from the backend ("http://127.0.0.1:8080", which is my callback).

When I try to request the data for it, I keep getting errors and undefined states. However when I just simply go to the callback redirect url and get data, it works perfectly What could be the issue? I set the necessary env variables

Here is my python and React code

React code:
[image]

Python:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, session, request, redirect
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask_session import Session
import spotipy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(64)
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SESSION_FILE_DIR'] = './.flask_session/'
CORS(app)
Session(app)

client_id = os.getenv("SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID")
client_secret = os.getenv("SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET")
redirect_uri = os.getenv("SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI")

@app.route('/')
def index():

    cache_handler = spotipy.cache_handler.FlaskSessionCacheHandler(session)
    auth_manager = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(scope='user-read-currently-playing playlist-modify-private',
                                               cache_handler=cache_handler,
                                               show_dialog=True)

    if request.args.get("code"):
        # Step 2. Being redirected from Spotify auth page
        auth_manager.get_access_token(request.args.get("code"))
        return redirect('/')

    if not auth_manager.validate_token(cache_handler.get_cached_token()):
        # Step 1. Display sign in link when no token
        auth_url = auth_manager.get_authorize_url()
        return f'<h2><a href="{auth_url}">Sign in</a></h2>'

    # Step 3. Signed in, display data
    spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
    return f'<small><a href="/sign_out">[sign out]<a/></small></h2>' \
           f'<a href="/playlists">my playlists</a> | ' \
           f'<a href="/currently_playing">currently playing</a> | ' \
        f'<a href="/current_user">me</a>' \



@app.route('/sign_out')
def sign_out():
    session.pop("token_info", None)
    return redirect('/')


@app.route('/playlists')
def playlists():
    cache_handler = spotipy.cache_handler.FlaskSessionCacheHandler(session)
    auth_manager = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(cache_handler=cache_handler)
    if not auth_manager.validate_token(cache_handler.get_cached_token()):
        return redirect('/')

    spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
    return spotify.current_user_playlists()


@app.route('/currently_playing')
def currently_playing():
    cache_handler = spotipy.cache_handler.FlaskSessionCacheHandler(session)
    auth_manager = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(cache_handler=cache_handler)
    if not auth_manager.validate_token(cache_handler.get_cached_token()):
        return redirect('/')
    spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
    track = spotify.current_user_playing_track()
    if not track is None:
        return track
    return "No track currently playing."


@app.route('/current_user')
def current_user():
    cache_handler = spotipy.cache_handler.FlaskSessionCacheHandler(session)
    auth_manager = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(cache_handler=cache_handler)
    if not auth_manager.validate_token(cache_handler.get_cached_token()):
        return redirect('/')
    spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
    return spotify.current_user()


'''
Following lines allow application to be run more conveniently with
`python app.py` (Make sure you're using python3)
(Also includes directive to leverage pythons threading capacity.)
'''
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, port=int(os.environ.get("PORT",
                                                   os.environ.get("SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI", "8080").split(":")[-1])))
```